# Test overridden save method in Django

Tags: python, django, testing, django-models

I have a Django model with an overridden save method to ensure that a special field (flag) is only set for one instance of this model at the same time.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.flag:
            for o in MyModel.objects.filter(flag=True):
                if o != self:
                    o.flag = False
                    o.save()
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then I wrote a test to ensure the intended behavior works.

```
from django.test import TestCase
from myapp.models import MyModel

class MyAppFlag(TestCase):

    def test_flag_is_set_only_once(self):
        o1 = MyModel(flag=True)
        o1.save()
        self.assertEqual(o1.flag, True)

        o2 = MyModel(flag=True)
        o2.save()
        self.assertEqual(o2.flag, True)
        self.assertEqual(o1.flag, False)
```

Unfortunately, the last assertion fails. I do not understand why because in general it works when testing the behavior in the admin interface (i.e. not in the test suite).

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't reloaded o1 from the database. Model instances don't update automatically when the db does: you need to explicitly fetch updated data.

```
o1 = MyModel.objects.get (pk=o1.pk)
self.assertEqual(o1.flag, False)
```

Note your save method is pretty inefficient: best to do it in one query:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(flag=True).exclude(pk=self.pk).update(flag=False)
```